# Four workers in a construction company

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, word-problem

There are four workers $A,B,C,D$ in a construction company with different skills. It takes $D_{AB}$ days when $A$ & $B$ works together to finish a construction, $D_{BC}$ days when $B$ & $C$ works together to finish the same construction and $D_{CD}$ days when $C$ & $D$ works together to finish the same construction. What is the maximum days it may take when all four workers work together to finish the same construction?

Comment: Negative vote without any comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I am tempted to do so.  [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/11206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c, \frac 1d$ be the fraction of work $a,b,c,d$ do in a day, respectively. Then we have the following system of equations:

\begin{cases} \frac{D_{AB}}{a} + \frac{D_{AB}}{b} = 1 \\ \frac{D_{BC}}{b} + \frac{D_{BC}}{c} = 1 \\ \frac{D_{CD}}{c} + \frac{D_{CD}}{d} = 1 \end{cases}

By adding the first and third equation we get that $\frac 1a + \frac 1b + \frac 1c + \frac 1d = \frac{1}{D_{AB}} + \frac{1}{D_{CD}}$. So they will need $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{D_{AB}} + \frac{1}{D_{CD}}}$ days

Comment: there is no $D_{AD}$ given

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah, it seems so. Then this problem has infinite amount of solutions.

Comment: no, the solution is $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{D_{AB}}+\frac{1}{D_{CD}}}$$

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah I kind of overlooked something. Nonetheless there are redundant informations in the problem